# SQL Alias an entire query

Tags: sql, join, alias, temp-tables

I have a query that I am trying to assign an alias to so that I can take a primary key that I made by concatenating some of the columns together against two other queries. The code goes like the below.

```
SELECT Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2, Table2.Col3 .... Table1.Col1+Table1.Col2+Table2.Col3 AS 'NewPrimaryKey'
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col3
```

Can I assign an alias to this query? Or would it be best to throw this into a Temp Table along with my other two queries and then Join across the three tables?

Comment: [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: CREATE VIEW?  CTE (Common Table Expression)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as other people suggested, you could do CTE, for example

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
SELECT Table1.Col1+Table1.Col2+Table2.Col3 AS 'NewPrimaryKey'
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col3
)
SELECT XXX
FROM Yourtable 
LEFT JOIN CTE1 ON Yourtable.XX = CTE1.NewPrimaryKey
```